# Separating data in pandas that has a variable format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a txt file that is an output from another modelling program where it is looking at parameters of a modeled node at a time. The data output is similar to the following below. My problem is the data is coming as a single column and is broken occasionally by a new header and then the first section of the column repeats (time), but the second portion is new. There are two things I would like to be able to do:

1) Break the data into the two columns time and data for the node. Then add the node label as the first column.

2) Later there is another parameter for the node, not immediately under where the information would be in the form Data 2 Node (XX,XX) that is the same as one previous.

This would give me 4 columns in the end with the first being the node id repeated, the second being the time, third being data parameter 1, and fourth being the matched data parameter 2.

I've included a small sample of the data below, but the output is nearly over 1,000,000 lines so it would be nice to use pandas or another python functionality to manipulate the data.

Thanks for the help!

```
Name  20 vs   2
----------------------------------

   time                    Data 1 Node(  72,  23)

     ---------------------      ---------------------
          4.1203924E-003            -3.6406431E-005
          1.4085015E-002            -5.8257871E-004
          2.4049638E-002             6.8743013E-004
          3.4014260E-002             8.2296302E-005
          4.3978883E-002            -1.2276627E-004
          5.3943505E-002             1.9813024E-004
....
Name  20 vs   2
----------------------------------
  time                      Data 1 Node(  72,  24)

     ---------------------      ---------------------
          4.1203924E-003            -3.6406431E-005
          1.4085015E-002            -5.8257871E-004
          2.4049638E-002             6.8743013E-004
          3.4014260E-002             8.2296302E-005
          4.3978883E-002            -1.2276627E-004
          5.3943505E-002             1.9813024E-004
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, can you format your df so their easier to copy

Comment: I'll have to see if the outputs can change. I ended up figuring out that I could use df = pd.read_fwf("data", widths=widths, names ...].
With this I was able to separate it using converting the second column to a string with df1= df["Items"].astype(str) and then looking through for known changes in the string with index1 = df1.str.contains("Prin. Stress 1").idxmax() and other indices. 
That told me which rows I could split on. Then I combined for the same nodes. Unfortunately now in my data frame I have these "-----------" cells and the time and heading columns. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a fair amount of googling I managed to piece this one together. The data I was looking at was space separated so I used the fixed file width read method in pandas, following that I looked at the indices of a few known elements in the list and used them to break up the data into two dataframes that I could merge and process after. I removed the lines and NaN values as they were not of interest to me. Following that the fun began on actually using the data.

```
    import pandas
    widths = [28, 27 ]
    df = pd.read_fwf(filename, widths=widths, names=["Times", "Items"])
    data = df["Items"].astype(str)
    index1 = data.str.contains('Data 1').idxmax()
    index2 = data.str.contains('Data 2').idxmax()

    df2 = pd.read_fwf(filename, widths=widths, skiprows=index1, skipfooter = (len(df)-index2), header = None, names=["Times", "Prin. Stress 1"])
    df2 = pd.read_fwf(filename, widths=widths, skiprows=index2, header = None, names=["Times", "Prin. Stress 2"])

    df2["Prin. Stress 2"] = df3["Prin. Stress 2"]
    df2 = df2[~df2["Times"].str.contains("---")] # removes lines ----
    df2.dropna(inplace = True)
```